# Unity3D update score error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial by Charger Games on youtube it's about street racer android game and I am seeing this error on the Unity3D's console it says 
 `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object UIManager.scoreUpdate ()`

This is the code that has line that caused the error

```
public Text scoreText;
int score;

void Start () {
    score = 0;
    InvokeRepeating("scoreUpdate", 1.0f, 0.5f);
}
void Update () {
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score; //this is the line. If I erase this the error will disappear
    }
void scoreUpdate () {
    if (gameOver == false) {
        score += 1;
        }
    }
```

If I remove it, the error will disappear. It's not causing malfunctions or anything, I am just curious cos I am willing to learn. Please help me guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say from this little code. You are trying to access (and set) a property "Text" of some object, but the field scoreText probably does not point to any such object. The same thing would happen if you had for example an array of ints such as int[] myArray = null; and then tried to read its property "Length" like so: myArray.Length which would also resultin null reference error. You need to first make the field reference the object.

In Unity, you probably forgot to drag the GameObject to the field "scoreText" of your script to establish the reference?

Comment: I did drag the score to the script. The scoring works just fine but I am still seeing the same red error on the console

Comment: Dunno then. What is this UIManager.scoreUpdate() method? Seems like your trying to update the score in two places: the scoreUpdate() and Update() of some script or what relation is there between those two methods? Isn't your score being updating even after commenting out the "scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;" line?

Comment: the scoreUpdate only increments the score while the scoreText only shows the score being updated as text

Comment: I'd remove the InvokeRepeating() as @MathieuAuclair said since you are already updating in the Update, but I don't think that's the cause. To debug, I'd put `if (scoreText == null) {Debug.Log("The scoreText reference is null");} else if (scoreText.Text == null){Debug.Log("The text property is null");} Debug.Log(String.Format("The calling object is {0} in scene {1}.", this.name, this.gameObject.scene.name));` in Update(). My guess is you atached the script to some other GO as well and you didnt attach the score gui object in that other script attachment in the inspector.

Comment: Hey I am so dumb. I found the error. In the game there are 2 scenes which both of them has the `UI Manager`. I dragged the `scoreText` on the level1 scene while the `menu` scene still ask for it. I fixed it by making a blank text just to substitute the `scoreText` on the `menu` scene. Thank you for your help. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `gameObject` isn't empty, the `gameObject` won't be selected by magic! So try this

```
public Text scoreText;
private score;

void Start() {
  score = 5; //example
}

void Update() {
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
}
```

[image: Inspector screenshot]

After that, you will need to assign your public `gameObject` and text to your script, so select the instance you gave your script and check in the inspector, you will see *[none(Text)]*, click on it and select your `UItext`

Have fun!

Comment: I added more codes. Yes I already dragged the scoreText there

Comment: try to remove Invoke repeating and that should work or stop update your UI in Update(), because you are updating twice

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html if you check here, they are using it, it might help you out ;)

Comment: Hey I am so dumb. I found the error. In the game there are 2 scenes which both of them has the `UI Manager`. I dragged the `scoreText` on the level1 scene while the `menu` scene still ask for it. I fixed it by making a blank text just to substitute the `scoreText` on the `menu` scene. Thank you for your help. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The famous null reference exception error occur when you try to access an object/refrence who is not initialized properly. Like Unity docs stated

> A **NullReferenceException** happens when you try to access a reference
>   variable that **isn’t referencing any object**. If a reference variable
>   isn’t referencing an object, then it’ll be treated as **null**. The
>   run-time will tell you that you are trying to access an object, when
>   the variable is null by issuing a **NullReferenceException**.([more](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NullReferenceException.html))

Now particularly in your question, you are trying to access **scoreText** object which is not assigned properly. Make sure that you have assigned **scoreText** in inspector where your script is attached.

Comment: Hey I am so dumb. I found the error. In the game there are 2 scenes which both of them has the `UI Manager`. I dragged the `scoreText` on the level1 scene while the `menu` scene still ask for it. I fixed it by making a blank text just to substitute the `scoreText` on the `menu` scene. Thank you for your help. Very much appreciated.